# i can't import nltk in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, nltk

I installed Anaconda and Python and while running this, I get this output:

[image: code to be reviewed in Juypter Notebook]

I want this to be like this when I import from `nltk.book`:

[image: desired output from import]

Comment: It appears the package you are attempting to install in your notebook is already installed.

Comment: thanks for helping! 
btw "from nltk.book import *" is not working at all,, what's the problem..??

Comment: Can you explain in what way it is not working? Do you get an error when you try to use something imported from it?

Comment: I would assume that it takes too long to actually import it. Can you try this in a terminal and see if this is a notebook related issue? 
Edit: I assume the code is working since it showed you the xml. The reason you are not seeing any response right now might be because your internet might be slow or again this might be a notebook related issue

Comment: As long as you see `In [*]`, just wait, it's still running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install :-

```
nltk.download('popular')
nltk.download('nps_chat')
nltk.download('webtext')
```

And finally

```
from nltk.book import *
```